In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, what is the added value of S3 storage of logs when CloudWatch is enabled for streaming logs
In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, there are two options for storing logs:

In S3: straight-up storage;
In Cloudwatch: stream the logs and retain them, with retention configurable.

If the logs are already streamed and stored in Cloudwatch, with the desired retention period, what is the added value of storing the logs in S3?
Is it best practice to stream & store the logs in Cloudwatch only, i.e, not store the logs in S3?
Enabling both options does not seem to be best practice?
